# Cacheleak vulnerability magento var folder issue

Tags: .htaccess, security, magento-1.9, crlf-vulnerability

I have scan my site using https://www.magereport.com. I got Cacheleak vulnerability? unprotected issue. I need to know to fix this issue i have to define `"location ^~ /var/ { return 403; }"` , please tell me where i will add this code , if in htacess how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a **.htaccess** file with below content in var/, var/cache, var/session, var/backups directory of your Magento installation. It will deny any access request made to files

```
Order deny,allow 
Deny from all
```

Refer to this article for implementation in Nginix server.

https://www.acunetix.com/vulnerabilities/web/magento-cacheleak

Comment: Isn't it enough to just put it under `var/` ??